# SQL output in powershell

Tags: sql, database, excel, powershell

I am connecting db and searching query which is stored in `$query`
Here is my connection function codes:

```
function ExecuteSql($Server,$user,$pwd,$database, $query){
$connectionString = “Server=$Server;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $Command
$Dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$DataAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
return $Dataset.Tables[0]
}
$rapor = ExecuteSql $Server $user $pass $Database $sqlquery
```

After using the function I am taking output of query in `csv` file but the output is not formatted; how can arrange the output my query like

```
$rapor >> result.csv
```

and I want to see output like

```
column :car                owners
line 1  mercedes           David
line 2  ferrari            hasan
line 2  bmv                Susan
..
```

I tried lots of thing but my output occurs like

```
120 ( which is range of my output)
mercedes david
********
ferrari hasan
********
bmv susan
********
```

...

Comment: The function supposedly works as expected - am I right?; please [edit] the question an add a [mcve] code where you do a conversion from the function output to a `.csv` file (you need to add a header line). BTW, please adjust my edit in case of the current output (it looks a bit unclear currently).

Comment: I made some changes does it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$rapor | export-csv result.csv -notype
```